# Problem with id of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem my `ListActivity`.

I have this xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and inside I have this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/flechas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textoName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textoPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUY"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:onClick="buy"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I use a BaseAdapter to show it, and this is the main file:

```
public class Info  extends ListActivity{

static ArrayList<Quotes> objeto= null;
static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lista= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
private ListView mainListView;
private InfoModel [] model;
private CustomAdapterInfo listAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);


    objeto= new ArrayList<Quotes>();
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    objeto= extras.getParcelableArrayList("datos");

    if ((objeto != null) && (objeto.size() != 0)){
        model= new InfoModel[objeto.size()];
        for (int i=0;i< objeto.size(); i++) {
            model[i]= new InfoModel(0, objeto.get(i).getName(), objeto.get(i).getTrade());
        }
    }

    ArrayList<InfoModel> datos= new ArrayList<InfoModel>();
    datos.addAll(Arrays.asList(model));

    listAdapter= new CustomAdapterInfo(this, datos);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

But my `mainListView` is null. It doesn't find the R.id.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your XML didn't come through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

I guess this should be your own ID. Like this:

```
android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
```

After that you can access it using something like:

```
mainListView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

If your activity extends the `ListActivity`, your XML should have a `ListView` with:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

That's correct. But, the way you initialize the `ListView` is different:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

This would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**"@android:id/list"**
means it is part of android package you can't call it using R.id.list( try this android.R.id.list) as R class generated for your package by ADT,instead you can get ListView object,
as **ListView lView=getListView()**
use setContentView method at top before you finding any View objects from XML(layouts),otherwise you will get NullPointerException.